# Making divs focus and change z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So basically we have a concept picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvS0a.jpg

Each of these window's is a div element on the site that on click should get on top. Let's say we click on window #2, that means that window 2 is on top now and window 1 is behind it. This is literally how the Windows operating system individual windows work.

Is this possible using jQuery and javascript?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: Could you point me on it?

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  Where is your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Set the `z-index` when click on a div, and set the `z-index` of the others to something lower

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $("div").not(this).css("z-index", "1")
  $(this).css("z-index", "2")
})
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color:white;
}

.one {}

.two {
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
}

.three {
  top: 70px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick example

```js
$(".window").on("click", function() {
  $(".window").css("z-index", 0);
  $(this).css("z-index", 1);
});
```

```css
.window {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.window:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.window:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 60px;
}

.window:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="window">W1</div>
  <div class="window">W2</div>
  <div class="window">W3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Carsten Løvbo Andersen answered, yes! it is posible, and he gave us an example that works using jQuery and javascript.

I just want to point out that it can be done by using css and html only, what answer the title of this question "Making divs focus and change z-index".

See modified Carsten Løvbo Andersen example:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container:focus {
  z-index: 1;
}

.one {}

.two {
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
}

.three {
  top: 70px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container one" tabIndex="0">1</div>
<div class="container two" tabIndex="0">2</div>
<div class="container three" tabIndex="0">3</div>
```